# Issue while creating a AD Group using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to write simple .net console to create Azure AD group using Graph API with the below code, however the code is not returning any error message and also when i try to run the code the group is not getting created.

What is the thing which i am doing wrong.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace AADConsole2
{
    class Program
    {

        private const string tenantId = "<<tenantid>>";
        private const string clientId = "<<client id>>";
        private static string appKey = "<<client secret>>";
        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CreateADGroup();
            
        }
        public static async void CreateADGroup()
        {


            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(appKey)
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            var testGroup = new Group
            {
                    Description = "testgroupdescription",
                    DisplayName = "testgroupkk",
                    GroupTypes = new List<String>()
                    {},
                    MailEnabled = false,
                    MailNickname = "testnickname",
                    SecurityEnabled = true,
                    //AdditionalData = additionalDataGroupB
            };

            await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(testGroup);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What permissions did you grant?

Comment: I have given the following API permission directory.readwrite, directory.read,group.create,group.readwrite

Comment: Are you granting application permissions or delegated permissions?

Comment: Its an application permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code, and although no errors were reported, it was indeed impossible to create a group. Because your code does not seem to be able to obtain the token, and you have not set the `scope` in the code.

I wrote the test code using the console application, and the local test can perfectly create the group. You can try it:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test

{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)



        {
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("{client id}")
                    .WithClientSecret("{Client Secret}")
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}"))
                    .Build();



            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            string accesstoken = result.AccessToken;

            /*Console.WriteLine(accesstoken);*/


            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(app);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            var testGroup = new Group
            {
                Description = "testgroupdescription",
                DisplayName = "testgroup1",
                GroupTypes = new List<String>()
                { },
                MailEnabled = false,
                MailNickname = "testnickname",
                SecurityEnabled = true,
                //AdditionalData = additionalDataGroupB
            };

            await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(testGroup);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @krishna  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @krishna Hi,  If you have any questions, please feel free to call me.